# Crystal Reports Improperly Encoding Hyphens On Export to Word

Tags: c#, character-encoding, crystal-reports

I'm having a problem with a generated word document (coming from crystal reports engine via a C#.net application).  Initially hyphens are visible but if the text is copied and pasted with "keep text only" option or "remove formatting option" the hyphen character gets changed to a blank space" ".

I'm quite sure this is an issue with the encoding of the character, probably it is encoded as soft hyphen.  Is there any way to resolve this via the crystal report engine.

I have already checked and confirmed that the source text is an actual hyphen character in the database.

Comment: Have you confirmed the identity of the character (in the database) by its Unicode number, or only by its appearance? The common Ascii hyphen, HYPHEN-MINUS “-” U+002D may look very similar or even identical to HYPHEN “‐” U+2010. And why does the title say “Soft Hyphen”?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela the data in sql is indeed unicode "002D".  This was the first thing I checked.  I can even type a unicode "002D" into a text box run the report and it comes up in word as a non unicode hyphen.  It has soft hypen because I believed that was the name for this issue https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html

Comment: Soft hyphen is U+00AD, and Word displays it as a visible hyphen (instead of implementing its Unicode semantics). It seems that the question is how (and why) U+002D gets converted to some non-character data when generating the Word document. What does the situation look like in Word in “Show All” mode (the one you can enter by clicking on the “¶” button or using “Ctrl )”)?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Show all continues to show a hyphen (although longer) and when I hit alt+x on it still shows no Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the common Ascii hyphen, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS in Unicode, gets converted to a code that is treated as Nonbreaking Hyphen in Word. A comment says that in “Show All” mode in Word, it looks like a hyphen, but longer. This means that it looks like an en dash “–”. Internally, it is byte 1E hexadecimal, so we could say that it is the control character U+001E. But it is unaffected by the use of <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. And if you copy text containing it and paste it as plain text, it gets replaced by U+0020 SPACE, so it’s really treated as a special code and not as a character.

It is *not* at all the same as NON-BREAKING HYPHEN U+2011 in Unicode; instead, it is Microsoft’s own idea of handling a situation where you want a hyphen to appear but don’t want Word to break a string into two lines after a hyphen (e.g., in the string “F-1”, where such a break would look ridiculous).

So you could try to find how this happens in the report engine and to prevent it. But it may be something more complicated than just replacing “-” by the bye 1E.

If you need to deal with the issue in Word, you can use Find and Replace, where the special characters menu contains “Nonbreaking Hyphen”. You could replace it by the common hyphen “-”, losing the non-breakability.

You could alternatively replace it by NON-BREAKING HYPHEN U+2011, which would preserve that property. But this might cause problems if transferred to other programs, or due to font problems (not all fonts contain that character). The font problem can be tricky: Word automatically switches to another font when needed and does not inform about this, so your text might contain characters in different fonts, which may cause problems of many kinds (such as uneven line spacing). Moreover, when U+2011 is present, it may look different from the common Ascii hyphen; it more or less should. Typographically, if you use U+2011, your normal (breaking) hyphens should be U+2010 HYPHEN.